# Server-Side Application Layer Cloud Authentication Patterns

Tags: authentication, ssl, oauth, client-certificates

What are some server-side application layer security patterns for authenticating role-based sessions, specifically across multiple virtual private and public networks? Looking for solutions that minimize code complexity for developers and reduces maintenance for IT.

Problem: The need is to get server-side applications that are hosted in separate private virtual clouds to delegate an authenticated session in a vendor-neutral (non AWS/Azure) mechanism.

Scenario: An application with an authenticated session, in the format of a JWT, needs to invoke a server across another network, delegating the JWT session but keeping it alive without invalidating its own session.

Possible patterns and their pitfalls:

1. OAuth: Spec has many flows, none which are concrete implementations, so doing it right is up to you. Requires a central identity provider service. Use of expiring tokens makes session state management difficult. Point of failure is leakage of client id and secret.
2. TLS Mutual Client Certificates: Requires certificate lifetime management (pain for IT) and additional code to validate certificates (pain for dev). For public servers, you need a public certificate authority and DNS, which increases costs and complexity as assumes as a cert has been requested for a dns. Point of failure are leaked private keys and rouge certificates.

Related Question: [OAuth 2.0 Many to Many Delegated Client Credential Flow Scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305577/oauth-2-0-many-to-many-delegated-client-credential-flow-scenario)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common approach to securing applications across vendor agnostic data centers is to use a brokered authentication pattern. The components of brokered authentication may include a combination of:

1. Security Token Service (STS) to verify credentials and generate tokens.
2. User/Pass or Application Key/Id and Secret.
3. KPIs (X.509 Client Certificates). Certificates are far more secure than plain text secrets and passwords. Validating certificates can be done with certificate authorities but they introduce their own problems. If the client has a pre-existing trust relationship, certificate pinning may be a solution to CAs (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning).

See Web Service Security: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/d/6/8d608524-0763-48b5-840b-0ae446996a14/MS_WSS_Dec_05.pdf

Public key infrastructure: https://sites.google.com/a/ssl4net.com/www/technology/public-key-infrastructure